# Obtaining parcel GIS data controlled by a private company that uses public information/funds to maintain it?

Tags: gis, arcgis

Wondering if anyone has run into this issue when obtaining GIS data and if there is a solution:

I am attempting to create a Locator in ArcGIS for Southern California and I've found that using parcel data greatly improves the accuracy and match rate. So far, most counties provide this information on their public GIS portals. San Luis Obispo and Orange County said they cannot provide the data because it is maintained by a third party ([ParcelQuest](https://www.parcelquest.com/)) and therefore is licensed. However, the public agencies display the data in web maps along with attribute information on their websites:

Orange County: https://www.ocgis.com/ocpw/landrecords/

San Luis Obispo: https://www.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=3e0adee3aabd4805bd13f0d4705a4193

If I am interpreting the *[California Public Records Act (California Government Code §§ 6253)](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?sectionNum=6253.&lawCode=GOV)* correctly, this data has to be provided to any citizen who requests it since the public agency is paying the private company with taxpayer money to maintain it and the public agency displays it on their own website. It even says on the [ParcelQuest](https://www.parcelquest.com/) website they update their data "daily straight from the county assessor".

> 6253. (f) In addition to maintaining public records for public inspection during the office hours of the public agency, a public
>       agency may comply with subdivision (a) by posting any public record on
>       its internet website and, in response to a request for a public record
>       posted on the internet website, directing a member of the public to
>       the location on the internet website where the public record is
>       posted. However, if after the public agency directs a member of the
>       public to the internet website, the member of the public requesting
>       the public record requests a copy of the public record due to an
>       inability to access or reproduce the public record from the internet
>       website, the public agency shall promptly provide a copy of the public
>       record pursuant to subdivision (b). (Amended by Stats. 2019, Ch. 695,
>       Sec. 1. (AB 1819) Effective January 1, 2020.)
>
> 6253.3.   A state or local agency may not allow another party to control the disclosure of information that is otherwise subject to
> disclosure pursuant to this chapter.
>
> 6253.31.   Notwithstanding any contract term to the contrary, a contract entered into by a state or >local agency subject to this
> chapter, including the University of California, that requires a
> private entity to review, audit, or report on any aspect of that
> agency shall be public to the extent the contract is otherwise subject
> to disclosure under this chapter. (Added by Stats. 2008, Ch. 62, Sec.
> 2. Effective January 1, 2009.)

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This probably belongs on the gis stack exchange, but I can tell you that a quick look at the network tab while looking at the SLO site will give you the arcgis server url of the data you are looking for:

https://maps.slocity.org/hosting/rest/services/slogisLayers/MapServer/

You can open these directly in the arcgis map viewer, so it doesn't appear that you need a special organizational membership to consume these layers.  The same is true on the OC site, though I only see basemaps there, not parcel data?

I'm not sure who you talked to, but just because the county pays some third party like ParcelQuest to manage their data, doesn't mean its not publicly available.  Very interesting question though about the access to data that is publicly owned but privately managed.  Please report back if you are able to access the layers directly through the arcgis server url!

Comment: Thank you. I am able to open the data in Arc Pro, but I need the actual files to create the Locator (for the "Create Locator" tool)...unless there is something I'm missing?

Comment: What do you mean by 'actual files'?  You mean the shapefiles that the layers are based on?

Comment: I suspect that https://law.stackexchange.com/ is a better place - gis.stackexchange is unlikely to have a better answer on the legal issues raised.

Comment: @SethLutske yes, the shapefiles.

Comment: I'm no Arcgis Pro pro (no pun intended), but I think there is a way to export from a featurelayer service to shapefile.  Can you bring the layers into arcgis pro from the service url, then export to shapefile / geodatabase?

Comment: @SethLutske no, I am not able to, but sometimes you can with other data. The creator of the layer can disable users from creating a shapefile out of it.

Comment: If that's the case then I think @IanTurton may be on the right track.  You'll either need to find the right person to talk to who can hook you up with what you need, or you'll need to consult a legal expert on how to extract the data you need.  In the mean time, I feel there must be a way to extract that information, though I'm not sure how.  Good luck!